# How to implement Web API Action selector in .NET 8

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, middleware

I have a `TestController` with two methods like this:

```cs
[ApiController]
public class RedoxController : ControllerBase
{
    [Route("api/redox")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Verify([FromBody] VerifyDestinationModel verification)
    {
    }

    [Route("api/redox")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult DynamicRequest([FromBody] dynamic dynamicModel)
    {
    }
}
```

I am using the API URL to call `https://localhost:5065//api/redox`.

Now I want to create action filter and action filter decide which method like (Verify OR DynamicRequest) need to call.

I tried to implement `IActionDescriptorProvider` but this is not working for me
and this is working fine in ASP.NET MVC but not in ASP.NET Core

Comment: Why not just have different URLs? Also, any time you use `dynamic`, a kitten dies.

Comment: How is the runtime supposed to guess what method to use? Using what criteria? Both methods match `VerifyDestinationModel`. This is a matter of routing, not filtering

Answer (score 0):

But you want same route, how about this:

```
        [Route("api/redox")]
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult DynamicRequest([FromBody] dynamic dynamicModel)
        {
            try
            {
                VerifyDestinationModel verification = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<VerifyDestinationModel>(dynamicModel);
                verification code...
            }
            catch
            {
                dynamicModel code...
            }                   
        }
```

Comment: Using exceptions for routing is a very expensive (and bad) idea. It's also a security vulnerability too - any kind of exception will skip verification